# ListBoxDragDropTarget : Can get it to work

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have a Silverlight 4 Business Application, I've installed Silverlight Toolkit April 2011 and added the reference to the project. I want to to reorder a listbox using drag and drop.

My code is the following:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <toolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True">
        <ListBox  AllowDrop="True" Name="listBox1">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>

                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </toolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget>
  </Grid>
```

And

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.ItemsSource = new Int32[] {1,2,3,4,5 };
        }
```

When trying to drag an item I see the "ghost" of the item and an icon whth two arrows (an up and a down arrow) but when I drop it (in the same listbox) nothing happens! It doesnt get reordered.

What am I doing wrong???
Do I have to listen to an event and implement something??

Thanks!

EDIT: The complete code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace editorencuestas
{
    public partial class testdragdrop : Page
    {
        public testdragdrop()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.ItemsSource = new Int32[] {1,2,3,4,5 };
        }

    }
}
```

AND

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="editorencuestas.testdragdrop" 
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
           xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
           d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
           Title="testdragdrop Page" xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" Loaded="Page_Loaded">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <toolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True">
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Height="175" Width="147">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
        </toolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget>
        </Grid>
</navigation:Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you pls try this?

```
        <ListBox x:Name="yourListBox">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
```

Sorry I was wrong.

If you do this it will work.

```
        var list = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);
        list.Add(3);

        listBox1.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: Tried that with <StackPanel/> instead <StackPanel> but its the same

Comment: Perfect! It worked perfectly! By the way, why does the listbox need an observable collection??

Comment: i found this '4.  If an item is dropped onto the drag drop target, it is added to the nested control if the nested control is bound to an ObservableCollection (or any collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged and contains the same type of items as the item that was dropped).' from http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2009/08/new-with-silverlight-toolkit-drag-and.html